# How to inject a class for all option elements from wp_get_archives()?

Tags: posts

I'm generating a list of all posts in a dropdown like so:

```
wp_get_archives('type=postbypost&format=option&show_post_count=0');
```

This works, but doesn't allow me to modify/add things to each option element.  The result needs to look something like this:

```
<select>
    <option value="">Select Post</option>
    <option class="level-0" value="285">20 Most Popular Health Care Products</option>
    <option class="level-0" value="305">About</option>
</select>
```

with the "value" being the post ID.

Essentially I'm looking for a `wp_dropdown_posts()` but there is no such function.  How can I replicate the behavior of `wp_dropdown_pages()` but for posts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If there is none, we can write one:

```
function my_very_own_wp_dropdown_posts($args) {
    $args = shortcode_atts(array(
        'posts_per_page'   => 5,
        'offset'           => 0,
        'category'         => '',
        'category_name'    => '',
        'orderby'          => 'date',
        'order'            => 'DESC',
        'include'          => '',
        'exclude'          => '',
        'meta_key'         => '',
        'meta_value'       => '',
        'post_type'        => 'post',
        'post_mime_type'   => '',
        'post_parent'      => '',
        'author'       => '',
        'post_status'      => 'publish',
        'suppress_filters' => true,
        'echo' => true
    ), $args, 'wp-dropdown-posts');
    $echo = $args['echo'];
    unset($args['echo']);
    $all_posts = get_posts( $args );
    $output = false;
    if ($all_posts) :
        $output = '
            <select name="archive-dropdown">
                <option value="">'. esc_attr( __( 'Select Post' ) ).'</option>';
        foreach ($all_posts as $post) :
            setup_postdata($post->ID);
            $output .= "<option class='level-0' value='$post->ID'>".$post->post_title."</option>";
        endforeach;
        wp_reset_postdata();
        $output .= '</select>';
    endif;
    $result = $output ?: esc_attr( __( "No posts found")).'.';
    if ($echo) echo $result; else return $result;
}
add_shortcode('wp-dropdown-posts', 'my_very_own_wp_dropdown_posts');
```

To get a dropdown with all your posts, just add `[wp-dropdown-posts post_per_page="-1"]` in any post or page (by default it only brings 5). If you want to use it in backend, you'll have to wrap it in a `do_shortcode()`:

```
do_shortcode("[wp-dropdown-posts post_per_page="-1"]");
```

**Important:** If you only want the `HTML` of the `select` returned, not echoed so you can echo it yourself inside a more complex function/class/plugin, replace `echo` with `return` in this line:

```
echo $output ?: __("No posts found").'.';
```

If you have more than 10 posts, you might want to combine this with a visual helper for selects (such as [WP Chosen](https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-chosen/), a WordPress plugin wrapper for [Chosen](https://harvesthq.github.io/chosen/)). *While I recommend the library, I am not endorsing the WordPress plugin, nor have I extensively tested it. It's just an example and it's up to you to research and find a better one for the purpose.*

If you have more than 50 posts, you might want to consider testing [this plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/select2-post-selector/) for your purpose, which has the advantage of dynamically populating your dropdown with search results based on what you type in. Typically, you want to avoid selects with more than 30 options. Again, I am not endorsing or supporting the plugin, nor have I tested it. It's a(nother) WordPress plugin wrapper for [Select2](https://select2.github.io/).

And, if you have more than 1000 posts, you might consider harnessing the power of [Solr](http://lucene.apache.org/solr/) (or any other viable alternative). A quick search has revealed someone already made a Solr plugin for WordPress. [Again, untested](https://wordpress.org/plugins/wpsolr-search-engine/).

---

Updated the code based on the extra info from comments. Also added an `echo` paramter, `true` by default.

Comment: Thank you very much for the code, much appreciated!  However I'm not looking to use this as a shortcode or in a post or page, I need this for a plugin so I merely want a function that returns exactly as wp_dropdown_pages does.  I tried taking just the function from your code and utilizing it directly but all output dies as soon as your code is reached.  I'm troubleshooting myself but if you have any suggestions on how to make this work as a simple direct function, I'd appreciate the guidance.  Thanks again!

Comment: I only tested it in frontend before I posted. Where exactly in backend do you want to display this dropdown? In what page?

Comment: OK the silent failure was my own fault, have fixed that and will figure out what else I need.  I'm displaying this dropdown in the back end inside another plugin that currently only offers a list of pages.  I'm modifying it to support posts as well.  I can probably figure it out from here, if not I will post back and if I ultimately succeed with your code then I will accept as best answer.  Thanks again!

Comment: Ive decided to go straight to the core source for wp_dropdown_pages (wp-includes/post-template.php) and see about modifying it to provide a list of posts, so that my _posts version's use will be identical to _pages.  I thought it would be quite easy to do but that's not turning out to be the case.  Any input on how to alter it to return posts would be fantastic.  =)

Comment: I seem to have gotten where I needed by utilizing this very old plugin and making a few small modifications:  https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-dropdown-posts/ .  Still, your answer got me thinking in this direction so I'm going to go ahead and accept it.  Thanks!

Comment: Updated answer based on the extra provided info.